# How to handle huge array when load in list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friends tell me how to handle larges array in app I have 9 different types array list in every list 22 words is sound and images.Images store in assets folder size 1.5 mb around only and sound comes from firebase cloud storage problem is that when app is load it slow down my app performance please tell me how can optimise it when run it show me

```
I/Choreographer(25037): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(25037): Skipped 3 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(25037): Skipped 8 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(25037): Skipped 6 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(25037): Skipped 3 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

but works I need to optimize it here is my code of array

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hebrew/Deteilpage.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp()
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.green),
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   var  hebrewword=['א','בּ','ג','ד','ה','ו','ז','ח','ט','י ','כּ','ל','מ','נ','ס ','ע','פּ','צ','ק','ר','שׁ','ת'];
   var imagelist=['images/a.jpg','images/b.jpg','images/c.jpg','images/d.jpg','images/e.jpg','images/f.jpg','images/g.jpg','images/h.png',
   'images/i.jpg','images/j.jpg','images/k.jpg','images/l.jpg','images/m.jpg','images/n.jpg','images/o.jpg','images/p.jpg','images/q.jpg',
   'images/r.png','images/s.png',
   'images/t.jpg','images/u.jpg','images/v.jpg'];
    var romanurduword=['Aleph','Beit','Gimel','Dalet','Hey','Vav','Zayin','Khet','Tet','Yod','Kaf','Lamed',
   'Mem','Nun','Samekh','Ayin','Peh','Tsade','Qof','Resh','Shin','Tav'];
    var englishword=[
      'Alpeh is for A-BA(Father)',
      'Beith is for Bah-yeet (House)',
      'Gimel is for Glida (Ice-cream)',
      'Dalet is for delet ( Door )',
      'Hey is for Ha.le.lu.Ya (worship)',
      'Vav is for Vanil (Vanilla)',
      'Zayin for Zebra',
      'Khet is for Cho desh (month)',
      'Tet is for Tallith (Prayer Shawl)',
      'Yod is for Yada & im',
'Kaf is for KEH-lehv (Dog)',
      'Lamed for lechem(bread)',
      'Mem is for MAH-goh',
      'Nun is for Ner ( lamp)',
      'Samekh is for Sus ( Horse)',
      'Ayin is for etz ( tree)',
      'Peh is for Perakh ( Bud)',
      'Tsade is for tzitzit',
      'Qof is for Qaseth ( Bow & arrow )',
      'Resh is for ROHSH (Head)',
      'Shin is for Shofar',
      'Tav is for torah'

    ];
var hebrewprounce=['אלֶף ','בּית','גָימֵל','דָּלֶת','הֵא','וָו','זַיִן','חֵת','טֵית','יוֹד','כַּף',
'לָמֶד','מֵם','נוּן','סָמֶך','עַיִן','פֵּא','צַרִי','קוֹף','רֵישׁ','שִׁין','תָיו'];

var audio=['aleph.mp3','beth.mpeg','gimel.mpeg','dalet.mpeg','hey.mpeg','vav.mpeg',
  'zayin.mpeg','khet.mpeg','tet.mpeg','yod.mpeg','kaf.mpeg','lamed.mpeg','mem.mpeg',
  'nun.mpeg','samekh.mpeg','ayin.mpeg','peh.mpeg','psade.mpeg','qof.mpeg','resh.mpeg','shin.mpeg','tav.mpeg'
];

var hebrewexplain=[

  'אַבָּא','בָּיִת','גֶּלִידָה',' דֶּלֶת ','הַלְלוּ-יָהּ','ןנִיל','זֶבְּרָה',' חוֹדֶּשׁ','טַלִּית','  יָדָיִים',' כֶּלֶב ','לֶחֶם','מַנְגּוֹ','נֵר','סוּס','עֵץ','פֶּרַח','צִיצִת','קָשֶׁת','ראֹשׁ','שׁוֹפָר','תּוֹרָה'];


var urdu=['آلیف','بیت ','گیمیل','دایت','ہے', 'و ','زائن','خیت','طیت','یود','کاف','لامیدھ','میم','نُون','سامیخ ','عائن','پے','صادی ','قوف','ریش ','شین ','تاؤ'];

var urdumeaning=['آلیف سے ابا(باپ)','بیت سے بایت(گھر)','گمیل سے گلیدہ(آئس کریم)','دایت سے دالیت(دروازہ)','ہے سے ہالیلویاہ(حمد و ثنا)','و سے ونیل(ونیلا)',
'زائن سے زیبرا(زیبرا)','خیت سے خوہدش(مہینہ)','طیت سے طالیت(دعا ئیہ پوشاک)','یود سے یادیم(ہاتھوں)','کاف سے کیلیو(کتا)','لامید سے لخییم(روٹی)','میم سے مینگواہ(آم)',
  'نُون سے نَیر(چراغ)',
  'سامیخ سے ثوث(گھوڑا)','عائن سے ایص(درخت)','پے سے پیرخ(کلی)','صادی سے صیعیت(جھالر)','قوف سے قاشیت(کمان)','ریش سے روشش(سر)','شین سے شوفار(نرسنگا)',
  'تاؤ سے توراہ(توریت)'
];

var urduword=['اردو  مماثل:ا','اردو  مماثل:ب','اردو  مماثل:گ','اردو  مماثل:د','اردو  مماثل:ہ','اردو  مماثل:و','اردو  مماثل:ز',
'اردو  مماثل:خ','اردو  مماثل:ط','اردو  مماثل:ی','اردو  مماثل:ک','اردو  مماثل:ل','اردو  مماثل:م','اردو  مماثل:ن','اردو  مماثل:س /ص',
  'اردو  مماثل:ع','اردو  مماثل:پ','اردو  مماثل:ص','اردو  مماثل:ق','اردو  مماثل:ر','اردو  مماثل: ش','اردو  مماثل:ت'
];
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hebrew Learning'),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: hebrewword.length,

        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return  GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(hebrewword[i],imagelist[i],englishword[i],audio[i],urdumeaning[i],urduword[i],romanurduword[i],urdu[i])));
            },
            child: Container(

              child: Card(
//                color: Colors.blue,

                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(hebrewword[i],imagelist[i],englishword[i],audio[i],urdumeaning[i],urduword[i],romanurduword[i],urdu[i])));
                      },
                      child: Container(

                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Directionality(
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              child: Text(hebrewword[i],style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
                                fontSize: 40,

                              ),),
                            ),
                          Image.asset(imagelist[i],height: 100,width: 80,),

                            Text(englishword[i],style: TextStyle(

                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),),
                            Text('',style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),),
                          ],
                        ),



                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    romanurduword[i],style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )
                                  ),
                                  Text(' / '+
                                      urdu[i],style:GoogleFonts.notoSerif (
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                                  )
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),


                              Directionality(
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                child: Text(
                                    hebrewprounce[i],style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
                                  fontSize: 26,

                                )
                                ),
                              ),


                              Text(urduword[i],style:GoogleFonts.notoSerif (
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                              )
                              )
                              ,
                              SizedBox(height: 20,),
                              Directionality(
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                child: Text(
                                    hebrewexplain[i],style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
                                  fontSize: 20,

                                )
                                ),
                              ),

                              Directionality(
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                child: Text(
                                    urdumeaning[i],style:GoogleFonts.notoSerif(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,


                                )
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are building all items in once. Instead of list view, use sliver widget which will build the widget upon scrolling.

Comment: I am beginner in flutter don't know about silver widget

Comment: added sample code, refer that.

Comment: TAKE NOTE: List view builder creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets that are created on-demand and doesn't build all items at once. So you DON'T need to switch to Sliver Widget. I need more snippet of your code of how you fetch your data from Firebase to be able to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Sliver` widget instead of using `ListView.builder`. ListVew wideget will build all widget at once, whereas by using `Sliver` widget you can build widgets when user scroll the screen. Refer the sample code below.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
    }
    
    class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      List<String> list = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 'Title 5', 'Title 6', 'Title 7', 'Title 8', 'Title 9', 'Title 10', 'Title 11', 'Title 12', 'Title 13', 'Title 14', 'Title 15', 'Title 16', 'Title 17', 'Title 18', 'Title 19', 'Title 20'];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                body: CustomScrollView(
                    //key: PageStorageKey<String>(myKey),
                    slivers: <Widget>[
                      SliverAppBar(
                        title: Text('Test'),
                      ),
                      _getSlivers(list, context),
                    ]
                  ),
                ));
      }
    
      SliverList _getSlivers(List myList, BuildContext context) {
        return SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return buildRow(myList[index]);
            },
            childCount: myList.length,
          ),
        );
      }
    
      buildRow(String title) {
        return Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)));
      }
    }
```